# Null Pointer Exception in sort() method

Tags: arrays, nullpointerexception

I get an error at:

```
if (this.words[j].compareTo(this.words[minIdx]) < 0
```

of this method.

```
private void sort() {
       int minIdx;
       Word temp;
       this.shrink();
       for (int i = 0; i < this.words.length; i++) {
           minIdx = i;
           for (int j = i+1;
                    j < this.words.length;
                    j++) {

               if (this.words[j].compareTo(this.words[minIdx]) < 0) {
                   minIdx = j ;
                }
           }
           temp = this.words[minIdx];
           this.words[minIdx] = this.words[i];
           this.words[i] = temp;
     }
}
```

I believe it is because of my shrink method

```
private void shrink()  
{
    Word[] randomWords = new Word[aWordCount];
    for (int i=0; i < uniqueWordCount;i++)
    {
        randomWords[i]=words[i];
    }
    words=randomWords;
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: it could be because of that function, but it could well be because of something else. Best is just to check for null (this.words[j]!=null) and be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, it could be anything; we'd really need to see the full code and some input to be sure.

However:

```
private void shrink()  
{
    Word[] randomWords = new Word[this.words.length];
    for (int i=0; i < this.words.length;i++)
    {
        randomWords[i]=words[i];
    }
    words=randomWords;
}
```

In other words, make sure you are not replacing the first array with one that potentially has another length (and might have empty items at the back).